# Laravel Linux Centos EC2 Mysql access denied

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel, amazon-ec2

Currently this is my `mysql -u root -p` credential

`UN : root`

`Pass:1234`

So I have this `.env` config on my server

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=sampledb
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

in Mysql I have these `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;`

[image]

the root user has the all privileges

I tried to restart my apache & mysql

also tried to `flush privileges` to take effect the privileges of the root user

also tried to

```
  php artisan config:clear
  php artisan view:clear
  php artisan cache:clear
```

But the problem is I'm still getting the error of `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

you can try deleting file `config.php` in the `bootstrap/cache` folder. Since laravel cache all the .env in this file.  Might be db connection is different in config file then in .env and `cache config clear command`

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Some times these command doest work if `bootstrap` folder doesn't have `777` permission